# Flutter - Tab Names Are Not Fitting In TabBar

Tags: flutter, tabs

I'm trying to add TabBar in my Flutter application. I will use 5 tabs with long names. For now, I added them like this;

```
DefaultTabController(
                  length: 5, // length of tabs
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelColor: Color(0xffd17842),
                        unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff52555a),
                        indicator: DotIndicator(
                          color: Color(0xffd17842),
                          distanceFromCenter: 16,
                          radius: 3,
                          paintingStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
                        ),
                        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(text: 'Cappuccino'),
                          Tab(text: 'Espresso'),
                          Tab(text: 'Latte'),
                          Tab(text: 'Espresso'),
                          Tab(text: 'Cappuccino'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        height: 250, //height of TabBarView
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))
                        ),
                        child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Display Tab 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Display Tab 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Display Tab 3', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Display Tab 4', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Display Tab 5', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ])
                    )
                  ])
              )
```

But the output is this;

[image: output]

I want it to act like Horizontal SingleChildScrollView with BouncingScrollPhysics with full long names. I can't fix it... Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `TabBar` set `isScrollable: true,`

```dart
child: TabBar(
  labelColor: Color(0xffd17842),
  unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff52555a),
  indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
  isScrollable: true, // this
  tabs: [
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, works perfect :) Just 1 more question if you know, as you see on picture, there is a white line in bottom of tabs. Even if I add `indicatorColor: Colors.transparent` line, it seems again. how can I remove it?

Comment: This is coming from `Container`'s `border`, you  can set width to 0 with transparent/ color.

Comment: can you write it ? as I search, only I see it with BoxDecoration

Comment: `indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,` with `top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),`
that will do the work, try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app, 
Does it solve now?

Answer (score 2):

set isScrollable property to true
 `isScrollable: true`

Comment: thanks for the answer, works perfect :) Just 1 more question if you know answer, as you see on picture, there is a white line in bottom of tabs. Even if I add indicatorColor: Colors.transparent line, it seems again. how can I remove it?

Comment: remove decoration of your second container.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by reducing the space between tabs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q47R3.png)

Comment: labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),// this